# Big mess with subversion - how to commit now?

Tags: svn, version-control

I've been playing with a project that's under source control for some time. I have added a couple of files, deleted some other files, and copied whole directories from another project, into this one. I have only now realised that some of those copied folders have .svn directories inside, but alas, at the moment it's impossible to figure out just looking at the project which .svn directories pertain to the current project and which ones don't.

I'm in great need to commit, and as expected, svn's giving me headaches. At first I got those naggy "Missing or not locked" errors, but after a lot of messing around I guess I really screwed things up.

So, how should I proceed to commit? Should I just wipe out all .svn folders (I'm not sure which ones correspond to this current project and which don't) or would that delete all info connecting each one of the files to the older versions in the svn server?

Thanks

Comment: It won't solve your current problem, but upgrading to 1.7 will help in future - all the `.svn` folders are consolidated into the root of the checkout.

Comment: One last resort is to delete all svn. folders, checkout a clean version, copy your changes (where you deleted the svn folders) over it, and commit that. Unless of course someone changed something in the meantime.

Comment: @dowhilefor: The project is quite big, I don't believe that'd gonna work.

Comment: @artbristol: That's nice to know. I wonder why it took them so long to understand the mess the pre-1.7 system was..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try the following:

1. Backup your (broken) Workingcopy
2. Checkout a clean working copy where you want to commit your stuff
3. remove in this (clean) working copy all **files** but keep all folders *and* the .svn folders
4. remove in your (broken) working copy all .svn folders, but keep all your files and folders
5. copy your broken working copy (which is not a working copy anymore as you removed the .svn folders) into your clean working copy
6. add all files which are new to your working copy (check with **svn status**)
7. delete all files which your working copy reports as missing(empty folders  have to me removed manually, sorry!)
8. now commit all changes to your repository

This should do the job carefully reviewing of svn status before committing is unavoidable, if something goes wrong startover again with your backup

Answer (score 1):

Wiping out all `.svn` folders is probably not what you need. Inside each `.svn` folder, there's a file called `entries`. In that file, the URL of the remote repo (don't remember the correct SVN wording anymore since using Git; sorry for that).

Assuming your regular repo is at `http://server1.com/myregularrepo` and you know that all the copied folders (that don't actually belong to your repo) come from `http://otherserver.com/otherrepo`, it shall be fine to search those `entries` files that contain `http://otherserver.com/otherrepo` and then delete their parent folder (i.e. their `.svn` folder).

If you have multiple foreign repo directories copied to your working copy, things will get a bit more complex, but I think you've got the hang of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is the way you want it I believe you can do an svn export (which removes all the .svn folders and then import it into your original project as a patch.